# Cannot figure out why it is failing to build

Tags: swift, xcode

when trying to build my app it keeps failing due to this error.
Does anyone know how to perhaps fix this?
Thank you,
Nick

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "___isOSVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
> -[AbstractActionSheetPicker createToolbarLabelWithTitle:titleTextAttributes:andAttributedTitle:] in AbstractActionSheetPicker.o
> -[AbstractActionSheetPicker configureAndPresentPopoverForView:] in AbstractActionSheetPicker.o
> -[SWActionSheet window] in SWActionSheet.o
> -[SWActionSheet initWithView:windowLevel:] in SWActionSheet.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Build *what*? Build *how*?

Comment: Sorry, should have made it more clear. I am having issues building my app in Xcode.

Comment: That's barely better than "I am using a computer and having problems." Ideally we need a *minimal example that exhibits the behaviour*, but at the absolute least we need more details on how you got here, like when your app went from being able to build to not.

Comment: I do apologize, I am quite new to programming, this is the first time of me trying to build it.

Comment: I'd start a new project to see if you can get that to work first. What are you trying to build? What template did you use? What's odd is this question references iOS but also x86_64 which is not a pairing that works as far as I know, iOS being ARM exclusively. If this is an iOS app you're building, check that your architecture is set correctly.

Comment: Those are linker errors.  Make sure you've added any frameworks/libraries you depend on in `Project Settings` -> `General` -> `Frameworks and Libraries`.  Also make sure in your build scheme that you've picked the appropriate device.  Since the error is saying that `___isOSVersionAtLeast` is undefined, I assume you're trying to build for iOS.